# PHP Coding not working for some weird reason

Tags: php

I opened a question about mkdir a couple min ago. I got that fixed. So here's question 2.

Now that I have the mkdir coding working, I tried implementing it inside my original file.

I've tried to debug the code, but whatever I do it's not working.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) { //1 Megabyte
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777, true);
   }
   else
   {
}
}
?>
<p>UPLOAD YOUR PROFILE PHOTO:</p> <br />
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">
<img src="./img/default_pic.png" width="70" />
<input type="file" name="profilepic" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Upload Photo"><br />
</form>
```

Some background info, I'm trying to create a profile photo upload page. It should, whenever I upload a image, create a folder with a randomly generated name. The thing is it does not create the folder.

Any ideas? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path as the parameter for `mkdir`, instead of a relative one?

Comment: Try a leading / like: mkdir("/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777, true); see if that makes a difference. And of course, print the path you're trying to create "/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name" to make sure it's really what you expect it to be, and make sure it's writeable.

Comment: Tried both things. Unfortunately both of them didn't work. The thing is, I've tested the mkdir and it works perfectly fine. I'm sure that something inside my code is not working 100% correctly, but I can't seem to find what exactly.

Comment: Please turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`), maybe there is some silent error message.

Comment: What does "@" in @$_FILES means?

Comment: @RomanHocke Nope, nothing showing up in there.

Comment: @ghopst - it suppresses errors and warnings - if `$_FILES` isn't set, you'll otherwise get a warning

Comment: @chris154 - What debugging have you done on this? When you say that the `mkdir` works, what does that mean exactly? How did you check that it works? What is the return value from your `mkdir` call?

Comment: @ghopst It prevents an error. It's kind of a workaround.

Comment: Maybe You have a typo in the form - it should read `multipart/form-data` instead of `multipart/formdata`. Your `if (isset($_FILES...))` is then false.

Comment: what errors do you get? what is in the logfiles ?

Comment: @andrewsi I took the mkdir code shown in the post and put it in a standalone file. When I executed that file, it generated the folder with a random name, like it should. I also tried commenting out some of the lines, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @chris154 - for future reference, you should avoid using `@` when you're developing. If you're getting an error, you should fix it, rather than ignoring it. In this case, the error message you were hiding would have explained exactly what the problem was.